# Confusion about a series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If for each p = 1,2,3,..., $\lim_{n\to\infty} (a_{n+1} + a_{n+2} +... a_{n+p}) = 0$, is it true that the series $\sum_n^{\infty} a_n$ converges?

I think so. My idea is that the condition implies all the terms more than n has a limit of zero, so the series is only the addition of the fixed term which will give a fixed value. However, I am having trouble comparing with the sum of $\frac{1}{n}$ which I think(not sure) also fulfils the condition. Can anyone help me to understand the difference between this question and the example of the sum of $\frac{1}{n}$.

Answer (score 4):

Take 
$$a_n=\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)$$
then for all $p$ we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n+\cdots+a_{n+p}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)+\cdots+\log\left(1+\frac1{n+p}\right)=0$$
but since
$$a_n\sim_\infty \frac1n$$
then the series
$$\sum_n a_n$$ is divergent.

Comment: why can't u just take an = 1/n?

Comment: Sure we can take $a_n=\frac1n$.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane, please write up a new proof with $1/n$ for the record.

Comment: The proof is the same just we replace $\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)$ by $\frac1n$@vonbrand